# How to save the replay of a previous played game using Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, destiny

I've just played a nice match, and I'd love to store it to view it again. I know I can record videos with Game DVR, but my question is...

Does Destiny provide any option to see (or save) the last game? Just like in theater mode from Halo series, in where you could find some last played games.

Maybe the Xbox One provides something to retrieve something without previously putting it into record mode? (more than 30 secs)

Comment: I dont know if Destiny has its own "theater" mode, but if you snap Xbox DVR, you can always say "end recording now", and it will ask you how much of the previous few minutes to capture, with a minimum of 30 sec and a max of 5 minutes.

Comment: @Dpeif, the minimum is 15 seconds, and you can easily capture without the need of Kinect or having the DVR snapped. They afforded more usability in a semi-old update they brought out for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no inbuilt way to record game-play, in Destiny. The only way to record prior activity is through the Xbox One DVR. That said, you suggest that the Xbox might have a way to capture prior game play, of longer than 30 seconds. In actual fact, the standard DVR system has this mechanic in place.

To increase recording time, access **Settings** > **All Settings** > **Preferences** > **Game DVR & streaming**. Select the **"Record that" records** option, and select the time-span. While the *default* recording time is 30 seconds, you can choose to record anywhere between 15 seconds and 5 minutes. Anything longer, and you will simply have to make multiple recordings, and use video editing software to stitch them together.

To record the **last** 5 minutes, simply press on the guide button twice<sup>1</sup>, and hit **X**. You will return to your game, and the last 5 minutes of game-play will be saved as a recording.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Pressing the guide button twice brings up the side menu, where you have quick access to things like your friend list, notifications and achievements. With this screen up, pressing **Y** will save a screenshot in-game, and pressing **X** will record the last 15 seconds - 5 minutes of game-play, depending on your allotted "Record that" time.</sub>

Comment: So if the game last more than 5 minutes, there is no other option to save your replay without going to GameDVR while playing the match?!

Comment: @SysDragon other than making a recording every 5 minutes, and stitching them together, no.

Comment: I *think* if you snap Game DVR, you can tell it to record the next so many minutes. But you'll need to keep starting the recording, and then combine the videos later.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a PlayStation 4, the system is constantly recording the last 15 minutes of gameplay. No need to hit record every 5 minutes and stitch videos together. Just hit "share" to save the last 15 minutes, then trim the video down later through the capture gallery app and upload it to YouTube :)

But as others have said, there is no other way to replay a previous match than recording it through the system or purchasing an external recording/streaming device.

Comment: Not only does he specifically say that he is playing on Xbox, but the question is asking specific to the context of an Xbox exclusive feature (see the tags). *The PlayStation 4 DVR may be similar*, but it is not the same as the Xbox One DVR.

Comment: I was backing up an answer and providing insight to the availability of such features in other consoles. Thanks for the down vote though, really contributes to the sense of community around here.

Comment: It is a nice thought, but we don't really recieve "commentary answers" very well. While posts like that add value in a forum environment, this is a Q&A site. Ultimately, "this feature works on PS4" does not answer "How can I use this feature on Xbox". To back up an answer, simply up-vote it.

Comment: Destiny is not an Xbox specific game. My answer is still a valid response. Your downvote is not. Had you provided a more complete answer to the question of "Does Destiny provide any option to see (or save) the last game?" (Which may I add is not an Xbox specific question), my answer would not be featured here.

Comment: I appreciate your interest, but it is actually a Xbox One specific question